# UITableViewCell not displaying text or NSMutable Array not set up properly

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to display a tableview populated by titles of RSS news feed items (MWFeedItem.title), using MWFeedParser.  The log says the feedParser is working fine, and there are no errors, but when I run it all I get is an empty tableview.

I started coding a month ago, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//
//  MS2TableViewController.m  

#import "MS2TableViewController.h"
#import "MWFeedItem.h"
#import "MWFeedParser.h"
#import "MWFeedInfo.h"
#import "MS2FeedTableView.h"

@interface MS2TableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MS2FeedTableView *FeedTableView;
@property NSMutableArray *FeedItems;
@property MWFeedItem *item;
@end

@implementation MS2TableViewController
@synthesize item;


- (void) loadinitialdata {

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.FeedTableView.delegate = self;
self.FeedTableView.dataSource = self;
self.FeedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self loadinitialdata];


// Create feed parser and pass the URL of the feed
{
    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL       URLWithString:@"http://images.apple.com/main/rss/hotnews/hotnews.rss"];
feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:feedURL];
feedParser.delegate = self;
feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull;
feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeSynchronously;
[feedParser parse];
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.FeedItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)MS2FeedTableView:(UITableView *)MS2FeedTableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
 UITableViewCell *cell = [MS2FeedTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

item = [self.FeedItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = item.title;

while (item != nil) {
    [self.FeedItems addObject:item];
    [self.FeedTableView reloadData];
}
return cell;

}


@end
```

Comment: what is this loop you have there `while (item != nil) {`

Comment: I deleted the loop, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized `FeedItems`

```
self.FeedItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

but never populated it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call;

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

when finishing parsing.

Also, make the connection async, we do not usually want to block the user interface.

Comment: I changed to async and called [self.tableView reloadData]; after [feedParser parse]; to no effect.